# What is the fastest method to merge pandas dataframe on a column while preserving the index of one of the data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider two dataframes:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ts':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'bt':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4]}).set_index("ts")
print(df1)
>>>
    bt
ts    
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    3
8    3
9    3
10   4
df2=pd.DataFrame({'bt':[1,2,3,4],'a':[1,4,2,5],'b':[2,5,4,9]}).set_index("bt")
print(df2)
>>>
    a  b
bt      
1   1  2
2   4  5
3   2  4
4   5  9
```

I want to merge them on the `bt` value which is the column in first df and the index in the second column while preserving the ts in the first data frame. Thus, the output I am seeking is:

```
    bt    a    b
ts              
1    1  NaN  NaN
2    1  NaN  NaN
3    1  1.0  2.0
4    2  NaN  NaN
5    2  NaN  NaN
6    2  4.0  5.0
7    3  NaN  NaN
8    3  NaN  NaN
9    3  2.0  4.0
10   4  5.0  9.0
```

It would be great if someone could suggest what is the best and fastest way to achieve the above combined data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = df1.drop_duplicates(subset="bt", keep="last")
x = x.merge(df2, left_on="bt", right_index=True).drop(columns="bt")
print(pd.concat([df1, x], axis=1))
```

Prints:

```
    bt    a    b
ts              
1    1  NaN  NaN
2    1  NaN  NaN
3    1  1.0  2.0
4    2  NaN  NaN
5    2  NaN  NaN
6    2  4.0  5.0
7    3  NaN  NaN
8    3  NaN  NaN
9    3  2.0  4.0
10   4  5.0  9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case do `drop_duplicates` then `merge`

```
out = df1.drop_duplicates('bt',keep='last').\
          merge(df2,left_on='bt',right_index=True).combine_first(df1)
Out[102]: 
      a    b   bt
ts               
1   NaN  NaN  1.0
2   NaN  NaN  1.0
3   1.0  2.0  1.0
4   NaN  NaN  2.0
5   NaN  NaN  2.0
6   4.0  5.0  2.0
7   NaN  NaN  3.0
8   NaN  NaN  3.0
9   2.0  4.0  3.0
10  5.0  9.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Left merge df1 with df2, then assign `NaN` to duplicated rows for a and b columns with keep=last.

```py
out = df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on='bt', how='left').set_index('ts')
out.loc[out.duplicated(subset=['a', 'b'], keep='last'), ['a',  'b']] = float('nan')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
    bt    a    b
ts              
1    1  NaN  NaN
2    1  NaN  NaN
3    1  1.0  2.0
4    2  NaN  NaN
5    2  NaN  NaN
6    2  4.0  5.0
7    3  NaN  NaN
8    3  NaN  NaN
9    3  2.0  4.0
10   4  5.0  9.0
```